# Pagination shows up but will not go past first page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

My pagination will not go past page one. I hover over the 2 link and it shows the link but it shows /page/2/, then when I click the link it does not append that to the end of the url.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
        if ($type == "events" ) { ?>
          <div class="row">
            <h4>Filter:</h4>
            <?php
              query_posts(array(
              'post_type' => 'events',
              'showposts' => 1,
              ));
            ?>
            <ul>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
              <li>
              <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
              <h3><img src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/images/icon_clock.png" />Date: <?php the_field('event_start_date'); ?> - <?php the_field('event_end_date'); ?></h3>
              <h3><img src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/images/icon_pin.png" />Location: <?php the_field('event_location'); ?></h3>
              <h3><img src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/images/icon_booth.png" />Booth: <?php the_field('event_booth'); ?></h3>
              <h3><img src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/images/icon_details.png" />Details:</h3>
              <p><?php the_field('event_description'); ?></p>
              </li>
            <?php endwhile;?>
            <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace the **showposts** with **posts_per_page**

example,

```
 query_posts(array(
          'post_type' => 'events',
          'posts_per_page' => 1,
          ));
```

Hope this will helps you.

For more details, please visit [WordPress Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)